# Receiving RuntimeError: COCO-Detection/faster_rcnn_R_101_FPN_3x.yaml not available in Model Zoo! while running Detectron2

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

After attempting a basic object segmentation, I received this error while trying to run it. I checked whether the model exists in Model Zoo and found that it was present. I tried it with different models as well and all of them showed the same error. How should I fix this?I am a beginner in Python.

Tried reinstalling detectron2, tried switching models but it didn't work

Comment: Can you provide the code that caused the error in the article or provide a minimum example for reproducing the problem?